# Add data attribute to table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to add a data attribute to a table cell using jquery? I have the following but it doesn't add a data-attribute to the `td`.

```
$("td.row").each(function( index ) {
  $(this).data("rowid",index);
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want the actual attribute to show up?

Comment: Because if you do, then you need to use: `$(this).attr("data-rowid", index);`

Comment: I used the inspect element tool in Chrome, but the data-rowid attributes don't appear in the `td` using the jQuery code.

Comment: `data()` stores atribitrary data on the element, it does not set the data attribute, but it can be confusing as `data()` will get the data attribute in some cases.

Comment: `.data()` allows you to store data associated with an element and it does allow you to get the data from already set `data-*` attributes. But it doesn't actually add `data-*` attributes to an element.

Comment: Shawn31313, your solution worked. I had `data` confused with `attr`.

Comment: I've made that mistake before as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.data()` allows you to store data associated with an element. It does allow you to get the data from element with an already set `data-*` attribute, but it doesn't actually allow you to add `data-*` attributes to an element.

`.attr()` allows you to add this attribute though.

```
$("td.row").each(function( index ) {
    $(this).attr("data-rowid", index);
});
```

You can also use @CrazyTrain's solution which seems a little more efficient:

```
$("td.row").attr("data-rowid", function(index) { 
    return index;
});
```

Comment: Or `$("td.row").attr("data-rowid", function(i) { return i });`

Comment: @CrazyTrain Good thinking. Had no idea you can do that.